# Python Multiprocessing with Subprocess Flags fail to run

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

When trying to run the following code I get

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The strange issue is that when I try to run LS without any other flags such as -a, the subprocess run as intended with no errors. I also tried adding shell=True along with the flag -a, but still no luck either.

```
from multiprocessing import *
import subprocess


class ThreadManager:
    def __init__(self, tools):
        self.tools = tools
        self.pool_size = cpu_count()
        self.p1 = Pool(processes=self.pool_size, maxtasksperchild=2, )

    def initiate(self):
        for self.tool in self.tools:
            print self.tool
            self.p1 = Pool(4)
            self.p1 = Process(target=subprocess.call, args=(self.tool,))
            print self.p1

            self.p1.start()

th = ThreadManager("ls -a".split("/"))
th.initiate()
```

Comment: `subprocess.call` should be called with `shell=True` to work with `"ls -a"` or have list of arguments passed like `["/bin/ls", "-a"]`. Why do you use `split("/")`

Comment: I am using `split("/")` because the result i get when running this without is
`l s - a` It breaks up the whole string intro characters. I cant seem to get shell=True working though. In other words running this
`Process(target=subprocess.call, args=(self.tool, shell=True))` 
Results in **Can't assign function to call**

Comment: Because `shell=True` is a _keyword argument_ (_kwarg_) while `args` accepts tuple of _postional arguments_. You should try to use `kwargs=dict(shell=True)` to pass it to `Process` or simply use `.split()` which turns `"ls -a"` into `["ls", "-a"]`

Comment: Thank you very much it seems to work now. If you wish to answer the question I will mark it immediately as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
"ls -a".split("/")
```

This turns it into a list `["ls -a"]` which forces subprocess.call() to find a binary named "ls -a" which doesn't exist. subprocess.call() can be called two ways:

```
subprocess.call("ls -a", shell=True)   # argument parsing is done by shell
subprocess.call(["ls", "-a"])          # argument parsing not needed
subprocess.call("ls -a".split())       # argument parsing is done via .split()
subprocess.call(shlex.split("ls -a"))  # a more reliable approach to parse 
                                       # command line arguments in Python
```

Note that first argument of subprocess.call() is a *positional argument* and passed as `args` tuple, while `shell=True` is a *keyword argument* and should be passed as dictionary argument `kwargs`:

```
Process(target=subprocess.call, args=("ls -a",), kwargs=dict(shell=True))
Process(target=subprocess.call, args=(["ls", "-a"],))
```